General questions on the "big picture" of scalar diffraction theory
When studying diffraction, my courses at university stopped with frauenhofer diffraction, which - as far as I understand it - describes the diffracted far field for diffraction of a more or less arbitrary aperture and states, that the diffraction pattern looks like the spatial Fourier transform of the aperture shape.
Recently, I wanted to learn a little bit more about the topic, and stumbled over software packages like the python library diffractio or programs like SpheroFront or Abberator used by astronomers to simulate their telescope's central obstructions' contribution to the PSF or the effect of Bahtinov masks.
Since I thought this was cool but could not find simple ways how such calculations are done, I wondered about the following questions:

I would like to understand the topic further and wonder if someone can explain the "big picture" to me, how different diffraction theories relate and what approximations are used? E.g. How is diffraction usually described in the general case (not with the approximations and limitations of Fraunhofer diffraction), e. g. arbitrary distances between image and diffracting aperture, or high NA systems? And is there some literature that does a good job of explaining it?

How is this calculation performed when studying the effect of optical systems on the diffracted light, e.g. when one wants to know how the diffraction pattern changes with defocus or other aberrations? Similarly to the calculations performed by the two astronomy software packets mentioned above, do? Is there some trick to just add wavefront error according to some Zernike polynomial and then again just doing scalar diffraction theory? Or is more detailed knowledge of the optical system, required?


Any explanation or hints to literature, that does a good job describing and illustrating "the big picture" is appreciated.

Approaches exist with names like "geometrical optics" (GO), "geometric theory of diffraction" (GTD), or "universal theory of diffraction" (UTD) and some others. The details are treated in the literature, for an overview see GO, Wikipedia, GTD-UTD, Wikipedia.
The big picture is that for very short wavelengths you can use GO, which means you only need reflections from surfaces (which could still be complicated if they are curved). With that approach you do not get light diffracting into shadow regions, it includes no diffraction. For longer wavelengths (compared to the size of the objects involved) you need to include diffraction from edges and for the best result even from corner tips. This is done by GTD, and if you use somewhat better mathematics for the light-shadow transition it's UTD.
The description is by rays that are diffracted by edges, at a location where angle of incidence to the knife-edge is angle of reflection, therefore they must be diffracted into a cone (the "Keller cone"). The formula for the amplitudes is based on Fresnel integrals.
A book I found useful is "Advanced Engineering Electromagnetics", by C. Balanis, which does treat this mechanism:


You can find it in other places as well, I'm sure. The most interesting thing mathematically is how the transition from light to shadow is smooth, when using the correct combination of all those integrals and factors and plus and minus signs (this usually does not work immediately if you try to program it...)

As far as I understood there is a general diffraction integral that describes the evolution f an arbitrary light field. Of this, approximations exist, called Fresnel approximation or - in the simple case - frauenhofer approximation for the far field. But I did not find any comprehensive and clear (at least to me) description of these.
Special cases like knife edge is not what I am interested in since there are many nice simulation codes and explanations available. Nevertheless, thank you for the suggestion of literature which I definitely will have a look at!

Fraunhofer probably is simpler! Just using Fourier transforms of aperture shapes https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fraunhofer_diffraction_equation and perhaps using Babinet's principle here and there can solve a lot of those problems. That saves the trouble of looking at all the edge lines that make up a particular shape and treat those separately with UTD.
